what has krishna said about arjuna?
read about the line in which krishna says no one is more dear to him than arjuna, so I was wondering in the epic how does krishna address him or what does he say about him? and why does he say he would raise arms if arjuna dies?

Lord Krishna has always said that Arjuna is his favourite.

Krishna say that he and Arjuna are one and same -


O invincible one!
You are Nara and I am Hari Narayana. We are the rishis Nara and
Narayana, born from that world in this world. O Partha! O descendant
of the Bharata lineage! You are no other than I. I am no other than
you. O bull among the Bharata lineage! No one can know any difference
that exists between us."


310 (13), Kairata Parva, Mahabharata.


Krishna says that he loves Arjuna more than anyone else -


Tomorrow, I will act so that Arjuna, Kunti’s son, can kill Jayadratha
before the sun has set. My wives, my friends, my relatives and my kin
are not dearer to me than Arjuna, Kunti’s son, is. O Daruka! Bereft of
Arjuna, I will not be able to look at the world even for an instant.
Therefore, it shall not be that way.


1033 (56), Pratijna parva, Mahabharata.


In a battle, the protection of my father, my mother, you, my brothers
and my life is not as important as that of Bibhatsu. O Satvata! If
there is anything that is more precious than the kingdom of the three
worlds, I do not desire it without Partha Dhananjaya. O Yuyudhana! I
am extremely delighted today.


1134 (157), Drona Vadha parva, Mahabharata.


There is no other man on earth whom I love as much. There is nothing
that I cannot give him, even my wives and sons. O brahmana! He is
unblemished in his deeds.


1295 (12), Aishika Parva, Mahabharata.


Bhagvad Geeta 10/37 - among Pandavas, I am Arjuna.
